# react native render view does not update after state changes auth component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, firebase-authentication

**Hi guys**

I am new to this react-native and I am trying to get the react-native, react router 4 and firebase auth to work. What I am trying to do is check if a user is logged in. If they are logged in it will show the "splash" component and if not logged in it will redirect to the '/login' screen.

I did follow the [react router 4 auth](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/example/auth-workflow) docs, but I just can't get it to work. Now I do wonder what I am missing here and if somebody could explain this to me so that I understand why it won't work.

This is the flow I am trying to achieve :

1. User can navigate to '/login' and '/register' when not auth
2. User can not navigate to '/' if they are not authed
3. When the user is authed they will go to the '/' and the component 'splash' is attached to that path
4. The component 'splash' have nested routes that are protected by the HOC

I am using the create-react-native-app for my project and this is my files.

**app.js (root component)**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        isAuth: false,
        email: "",
        password: ""
    };
}

onHandleLogin = (e, type) => {
    const event = e.nativeEvent.text;
    this.setState({ [type]: event });
};

onSubmitLogin = () => {
    const email = this.state.email;
    const password = this.state.password;
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

        .catch(err => {
            console.log("error:", err);
        });
};

isLoggedIn = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            this.setState({ isAuth: true });
            return true;
        } else {
            this.setState({ isAuth: false });
            return false;
        }
    });
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.isLoggedIn();
}

render() {
    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
                this.isLoggedIn() ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/login",
                            state: { from: props.location }
                        }}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );
    return (
        <NativeRouter>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        path="/login"
                        render={props => (
                            <Login
                                {...props}
                                submitFunc={this.onSubmitLogin}
                                login={this.onHandleLogin}
                                msg={this.state.isAuth}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                    <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Splash} />
                </Switch>
            </View>
        </NativeRouter>
    );
}
}
```

**Splash.js**

```
import Home from "./../Home/Home";

const Splash = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </View>
    );
};
```

**Login.js**

```
const Login = ({ login, submitFunc }) => {
return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.formContainer}
    >
        <InputContainer style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <Logo source={logo} />
            <Input
                inputStyle={styles.input2}
                onChange={e => login(e, "email")}
                placeholder="Email"
                clearButtonMode="always"
                containerStyle={styles.input}
                leftIcon={
                    <Icon
                        containerStyle={styles.iconContainer}
                        name="at"
                        size={20}
                        type="font-awesome"
                        color="#b2b2b2"
                    />
                }
            />
            <Input
                inputStyle={styles.input2}
                onChange={e => login(e, "password")}
                placeholder="Password"
                clearButtonMode="always"
                containerStyle={styles.input}
                secureTextEntry={true}
                leftIcon={
                    <Icon
                        containerStyle={styles.iconContainer}
                        name="lock"
                        size={20}
                        type="font-awesome"
                        color="#b2b2b2"
                    />
                }
            />
            <Button
                title="Log in"
                buttonStyle={styles.button}
                titleStyle={styles.buttonTitle}
                onPress={() => submitFunc()}
            />
            <Button
                title="Forgot your password?"
                buttonStyle={styles.buttonLink}
                titleStyle={styles.buttonLinkTitle}
            />
            <ForgotContainer>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Don't have an account? </Text>
                <Link component={TouchableOpacity} to="/register">
                    <Text>Create one</Text>
                </Link>
            </ForgotContainer>
        </InputContainer>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
);
};
```

I appreciate all the help I can get and an explanation, thank you guys in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged), [`onAuthStateChanged`](http://onAuthStateChanged) adds a **listener / observer and returns a non-null function(): The unsubscribe function for the observer.**.

> `onAuthStateChanged(nextOrObserver, error, completed) returns function()`

Looking at your code, there are two things that you are doing wrong

1. Reinitializing the listener again at the `PrivateRoute` component, which does nothing.
2. Not `unsubscribing` the listener, which may in turn, **add additional overhead**, whenever the *auth state changes for your entire app*

*The optimum way would be to proceed as follows*:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Bind the variable to the instance of the class.
    this.authFirebaseListener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,  // For the loader maybe
        user, // User Details
        isAuth: true
      });
    });

  }

componentWillUnmount() {
   this.authFirebaseListener && this.authFirebaseListener() // Unlisten it by calling it as a function
}
```

and in your `PrivateRoute` component, either inject it into your component (if you want your component to be separate, or else inject it directly) using `this.state`

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuth, ...rest }) => ( // Pass it as a prop where your component is injected
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
                isAuth ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/login",
                            state: { from: props.location }
                        }}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );
```

and

```
<PrivateRoute path="/" isAuth={this.state.isAuth} component={Splash} />
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me man. I understand now how this connects

Comment: stackoverflow says I can award you the 150 bounty in 21 hours, just so you know

Answer (score 0):

ot sure if this is issue but this.isLoggedIn is not calling function

this.isLoggedIn() is actually calling a function

Comment: one thing I see is that you don't wait until you know the results, which means your component will redirect

you need one more state variable saying - firebaseFetched or similar and do in render

if (!this.state.firebaseFetched) return "Loading...";

and in your onAuthStateChanged this.setState({firebaseFetched:true beside setting loggedIn

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check `this.state.isAuth` instead of `this.isLoggedIn()` in the App render function.

`this.isLoggedIn` is not returning anything and will always be falsy (undefined), so you'll always go to the redirect case.